# Is there any way for a section to link back to the table of contents in pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

So I'm able to create a nice table of contents with pandoc --toc option, but I was wondering if there is any way of linking the header or a symbol near the heading back to the table of contents. For example, when you create a footnote in pandoc, it links the subscript number to the bottom of the page. At the end of the note, there is this little sign (↩︎) with a link for going back to the line where the footnote was. I'd like to do this with my table of contents for each header. I don't mind not use --toc, and instead manually writing out the table of contents, but I not sure whether this particular feature was available. Any tips would be very helpful!

Comment: Which format are you targeting? Just HTML, or anything else, too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tarleb Just html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) can be used to add a link back to the TOC.

```lua
local link_to_toc = pandoc.Link({pandoc.Str '↑'}, '#TOC')

function Header (h)
  h.content = h.content .. {pandoc.Space(), link_to_toc}
  return h
end
```

Save the above into a file and pass it to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` (or `-L`) command line option.

Linking to a specific line in the TOC is not possible though.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I hadn't noticed this before but I did now. The table of contents also includes the arrow now. Is there a way to remove that. What I mean is, I want the arrow to stay in the actual header but not be included in the table of contents for each entry

Comment: Yes, you could add a CSS rule to your document to hide the arrow in the TOC, e.g. by adding `#TOC a span { display: none }` to the `header-includes` variable.

Comment: So some of my headers link to another document. The part of the header that forms the separate link gets hidden as well

Comment: I'm sorry I figured it out. I could just change the `span` to `span:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

The only 1 solution I found while generating the table of contents using `--toc` was to link to the first question for that scenario.

Alternatively, you can create `## Table of Contents` heading and link using `[Back to Top](#table-of-contents)`.

However, if you generate a table of contents using `--toc`, the `## Table of Contents` will come **below** the automatically generated actual table of contents. Hence, `[Back to Top](#table-of-contents)` would link to the header **below** automatically generated table of contents. Keep this in mind!